# How can I get three bits of text to line up left, right, and centre using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get three bits of text (styled to look like buttons) to line up left, centre, and right using HTML and CSS, no Flexbox or JS, but without success. How can this be achieved? This is what I need:

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
#row1 {padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px;
           overflow: hidden; }

.button-container {display: block; text-align: center;}

.button-left {
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: left;
    font-size: 75%; }

.button-right {
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: right;
    font-size: 75%; }

.button-centre {
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 75%; }
```

```html
<div id="row1">
<div class="button-container">
<span class="button-left"><a href="#1">previous</a></span>
<span class="button-centre"><a href="#2">issue</a></span>
<span class="button-right"><a href="#3">next</a></span>
</div><!--close button-container">
</div><!--close r1-->
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Have you tried putting `text-align:center` on the button *container* and removing all alignment/float from the others?

Comment: Ar you wanting to group all three buttons together like |   ---   | ?

Comment: I'm trying to get one at the left of the div, one in the centre, and one on the right, like this: | -     -     - | . The problem is that they are not at the same vertical position. In other words, they are not lining up horizontally properly, and I have no idea why. The container already has `text-align: center`on it. Removing it from the other divs doesn't change anything; removing the floats brings the outer buttons in towards the centre which isn't what I need. Where they are horizontally is fine; the problem is the vertical misalignment.

Comment: On-topic: how can I get multiple spaces to show up in a comment here?

Answer (score 1):

***Flexbox*** is ideal for this type of a problem:

```css
#row1 {
  padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: space-between; /* MDN: The items are evenly distributed within the alignment container along the main axis. The spacing between each pair of adjacent items is the same. */
  align-items: center; /* centers them vertically */
}

.button-left {
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 75%;
}

.button-right {
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 75%;
}

.button-centre {
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">
  <div class="button-container">
    <span class="button-left"><a href="#1">previous</a></span>
    <span class="button-centre"><a href="#2">index</a></span>
    <span class="button-right"><a href="#3">next</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternative without *Flexbox*:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}

#row1 {padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px}

.button-container {position: relative}

.button-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 75%; }

.button-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 75%; }

.button-centre {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 17px);
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 75%; }
```

```html
<div id="row1">
  <div class="button-container">
    <span class="button-left"><a href="#1">previous</a></span>
    <span class="button-centre"><a href="#2">issue</a></span>
    <span class="button-right"><a href="#3">next</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Changes made: `.button-container {position: relative}`, also added `position: absolute` to all the *children* with appropriate *values* of the `left` and `right` *properties*, for the *middle child* the *value* of the `left` *property* `calc(50% - 17px)` is calculated based on it's *width* (`padding` and `border` included) which is `34px` divided by 2 and deducted from `50%`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="row1">
<div class="button-container">
<span class="button"><a href="#1">previous</a></span>
<span class="button"><a href="#2">index</a></span>
<span class="button"><a href="#3">next</a></span>
</div><!--close button-container">
</div><!--close r1-->
```

CSS

```
#row1 {
        padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px;
           overflow: hidden; 
       }

.button-container {display: block; text-align: center;}

.button {
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 75%; }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that brings the buttons in towards the centre.

Comment: Ok then what exactly you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), assuming you just want all the buttons to be next to each other you can give your `.button-container` the property `display:flex;`.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85ex2rfL/).

Your button container is already a block level element, since you are using a `<div>` so you don't need the `display:block`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btns {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}
.btns a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.btns a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
  color: #FFF;
}
.btns a:first-child {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.btns a:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="btns">
  <a href="#">Previous</a>
  <a href="#">Index</a>
  <a href="#">Next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to just add a `<br>`tag after each button, line this:

```
    <div id="row1">
    <div class="button-container">
    <span class="btns button-left"><a href="#1">previous</a></span>
    <br>
    <span class="btns button-centre"><a href="#2">index</a></span>
    <br>
    <span class="btns button-right"><a href="#3">next</a></span>
    <br>
    </div><!--close button-container">
    </div><!--close r1-->
```